React 18 and react-cookie - problem tracing a cookie expiration
In my app I had to upgrade React to 18 version and it broken some functionality related to react-cookie package. Before the update I had and ability to trace cookie expiration and show a modal when it occurs.
Now when I use updateCookies() method from useCookies hook I see that a cookie I just set disappears for no reason.
Here's code
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = window.setInterval(() => {
      const date = new Date();
      updateCookies();
      console.log('tick', date.toUTCString());
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      console.log('CDU');
      window.clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);

and here's github repo with minimal code.
I'b very grateful for any ideas about solving this problem.
